# How to get ANY input from a MIC in c#

Tags: c#

So I want to be able to get anything the user says into a MIC and process it. I know I can use this:

```
Choices c = new Choices();
        c.Add("hello test one two three");

        GrammarBuilder builder = new GrammarBuilder();
        builder.Append(c);

        Grammar g = new Grammar(builder);
        g.Name = "CMDS";
        reader.LoadGrammar(g);

        if (sReco != null)
            reader.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(SpeechRecognizedCallBack);
        if (sHypoth != null)
            reader.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler<SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs>(SpeechHypothesizedCallBack);
        if (sDetected != null)
            reader.SpeechDetected += new EventHandler<SpeechDetectedEventArgs>(SpeechDetectedCallBack);
```

to get certain words, but how do I get ANYTHING the user says. I've heard of DictationGrammar but I can't seem to get it to detect my voice. Can anyone help? Also code examples would help alot.

Thanks.

Comment: try looking for NAudio. https://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: That won't work, I need to know what was said.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis

Comment: @theB sorry I don't understand what I'm to look at, at that link.